# How to sort sql output by division of two rows?

Tags: php, sql, database

I want to sort the posts of my site by the result of the likes (vote) divided by the views (postviews).

Is something like this possible?

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        from posts 
        WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT postid FROM postfeed)
        ORDER BY vote/postviews 
        DESC LIMIT 1";
```

This is a cron job that adds the id to the another feed table, that's why I have a limit of 1.

Comment: are the columns `vote` and `postviews` coming from the `posts` table?

Comment: i think you can do `order by vote/postviews` then..have you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you trying to do. If you want to order by calculation then do this trick

```
$sql = "SELECT p.*, p.vote/p.postviews as average 
       FROM posts p
       WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT postid FROM postfeed)
       ORDER BY average DESC 
       LIMIT 1";
```

You calc value for each row and then you should create alias for it and sort by this alias.

Comment: That looks like what I want! I will test it once the hosting people fix what's wrong with my cron jobs and accept your answer if it works.

Comment: It seems to be working as I ran it manually and it did choose the one post where the votes/postviews was biggest, even though it might have been coincidental as I have only three testing posts, but I will come back if I find out it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        from posts 
        WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT postid FROM postfeed)
        ORDER BY vote, postviews 
        LIMIT 1";
```

You can also add a parameter to make either of then Ascending or Descending sort like so :-

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        from posts 
        WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT postid FROM postfeed)
        ORDER BY vote DESC, postviews DESC
        LIMIT 1";
```

Or

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        from posts 
        WHERE id NOT IN(SELECT postid FROM postfeed)
        ORDER BY vote DESC, postviews ASC
        LIMIT 1";
```

Ah although @Robert may well have understood the question better.